# Allows authenticated users to tag content

Tags: users, taxonomy-terms

Administrator can add tags/Term reference to any content types. 
How can I give permission to authenticated users so that they can tag on any content type where they have access for editing/adding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for field permission. If authenticated user has permission to add/edit the node then user should be able to tag it. You Just need to verify your permission settings.